# .Net Unit test EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling issue

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library-5, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am using EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling Version 5 for error handling. Working perfect in project. But when run all unittest in project getting error:

> Strong name verification failed for the instrumented assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Please ensure that the right key file for re-signing after instrumentation is specified in the test settings.

Although if I run the particular test only in debug mode working fine as expected.

Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer it was becuase of Code Coverage is checked in Test --> Local Settings.
So i created a interface to mock the exception class like

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling;
public interface IExceptionHandler
{
    bool HandleException(System.Exception oex, string policy);
}


[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class ExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public bool HandleException(System.Exception oex, string policy)
    {
        return ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(oex, policy);
    }
}
```